# Pandas Dataframe calculating in intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
   time  value
0     1    214
1     4    234
2     5    253
3     7    272
4     9    201
5    11    221
6    13    211
7    15    201
8    17    199
```

I want to split it into intervals and calculate for every interval the difference for the values to the first row of every interval.
Result should be like this with an interval of 6 for example (the lines inside are just for better explanation):

```
   time  value  diff_to_first
0     1    214              0
1     4    234             20
2     5    253             39
--------------------------------
3     7    272              0
4     9    201            -71
5    11    221            -51
--------------------------------
6    13    211              0
7    15    201            -10
8    17    199            -12
```

With the following code i get the wanted result, but i think the code is not very elegant. Are there any better solutions (for example, how can i integrate the subset term in the loc statement) ?

```
import pandas as pd
interval = 6
low = 0
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 214], [4, 234], [5, 253], [7, 272], [9, 201], [11, 221],
                    [13, 211], [15, 201], [17, 199]], columns=['time', 'value'])

df['diff_to_first'] = None 
maxvalue = df['time'].max()
while low <= maxvalue:
    high = low + interval
    subset = df[ (df['time']>=low) & (df['time']<high) ]
    first = subset.iloc[0]['value']
    df.loc[ (df['time']>=low) & (df['time']<high), 
           'diff_to_first'] = df.loc[ (df['time']>=low) & (df['time']<high) , 'value'] - first 
    low = high
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new column "group". Then use groupby and apply you defined function to join column with diff by group. It will be more elegant. But I think, my way to create "group" column also can be more elegant = )

```
def diff(df):
    df['diff_to_first'] = df.value - df.value.values[0]
    return df

df['group'] = np.concatenate([[i] * 3 for i in range(0, len(df)/3)])

df.groupby('group').apply(diff)
```

Output:

```
   time  value  group  diff_to_first
0     1    214      0              0
1     4    234      0             20
2     5    253      0             39
3     7    272      1              0
4     9    201      1            -71
5    11    221      1            -51
6    13    211      2              0
7    15    201      2            -10
8    17    199      2            -12
```

Answer (score 1):

you can group the dataframe by value of interval and difference the grouped data with the shifting by 1 index

```
interval = 3
df['diff_to_first'] = df.value.groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)/interval),interval)[:len(df)]).apply(lambda x:x-x.shift()).fillna(0)
```

Out:

```
  time  value diff_to_first
0   1   214 0.0
1   4   234 20.0
2   5   253 19.0
3   7   272 0.0
4   9   201 -71.0
5   11  221 20.0
6   13  211 0.0
7   15  201 -10.0
8   17  199 -2.0
```